# Нужно остановить программу на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот условие задачи.

Даны значения двух моментов времени, принадлежащих одним и тем же суткам: часы, минуты и секунды для каждого из моментов времени. Известно, что второй момент времени наступил не раньше первого. Определите, сколько секунд прошло между двумя моментами времени.

Программа на вход получает три целых числа: часы, минуты, секунды, задающие первый момент времени и три целых числа, задающих второй момент времени.

Выведите число секунд между этими моментами времени.

Я уже сделал эту задачу, но мне ещё нужно, чтобы пользователь не ввёл в часы больше 24 и в минутах и в секундах больше 60.

Вот сама программа.

```
h = int(input())
m = int(input())
s = int(input())

h_2 = int(input())
m_2 = int(input())
s_2 = int(input())

if (((h >= 24) and (m > 60 and s > 60)) and ((h_2 >= 24) and (m > 60 and s > 60))) and h > h_2 :
    print('ERROR!')
    break 
else :
    continue

past_seconds = print((h_2 - h) * 3600 + (m_2 - m) * 60 + (s_2 - s))
```

Comment: Как заголовок связан с вопросом?

Comment: exit(0)   попробуйте вместо break, а else вообще уберите

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант. Только ввод сделал в две стоки вместо шести:

```
Введите значения первого момента времени `ЧЧ ММ СС`: 14 22 36
Введите значения второго момента времени `ЧЧ ММ СС`: 14 23 46
70
```

Попробуйте:

```
def is_decimal(hms1, hms2):
    ind = 0
    hms = ""
    for lis in hms1, hms2:
        ind += 1
        for i, z in enumerate(lis):
            if not z.isdecimal():
                return False, "Есть не целые числа в {}-м значении".format(ind)  
            if i:
                if not 0<=int(z)<60 :
                    return False, "Проверьте `ММ` или `СС` в {}-м значении".format(ind) 
            else:
                if not 0<=int(z)<24 :
                    return False, "Проверьте `ЧЧ` в {}-м значении".format(ind) 
            hms += "{:0>2}".format(z)
    if hms[:6] > hms[6:]:
        return False, "Значении 1 больше Значении 2"

    return True, "Данные введены правильно!"

flag = True
while flag:
    hms1 = input("\nВведите значения первого момента времени `ЧЧ ММ СС`: ").split()
    hms2 = input("Введите значения второго момента времени `ЧЧ ММ СС`: ").split()

    if len(hms1)==3 and len(hms2)==3:
        fl, er = is_decimal(hms1, hms2)

        if fl:
            h, m, s       = [int(i) for i in hms1]
            h_2, m_2, s_2 = [int(i) for i in hms2]
            print((h_2 - h) * 3600 + (m_2 - m) * 60 + (s_2 - s))

            # просто для проверки, т.к. писали что формула не правильная ：)
            print(((h_2 - h)*60 + (m_2-m))*60 + (s_2-s))

            flag = False
        else:
            print("-", er)
    else:
        print("\nВведите данные в правильном формате - `ЧЧ ММ СС`\n")
```